# In Wordpress, how to code a custom form with file upload option and save the records in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So far I have been able to make a custom form which upon successful entry save the value to a MySql table called "form_entry"

Below is the code for a form:

```
<form method="post" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="myname" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="John Doe" required>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
<label>State</label>
<input type="text" name="statename" class="form-control" placeholder="State" required>
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

And I insert a few codes in the functions.php under my template folder like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['BtnSubmit'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    $data_array = array(
                        'myname' => $_POST['myname'],
                        'statename'  => $_POST['statename'],

                        );

    $table_name = 'form_entry';
    $rowResult = $wpdb ->insert($table_name, $data_array, $format=NULL);

    if($rowResult == 1) {
        echo 'Success';
    }
else {
    echo ' Error in my pant';
}   
die;
}
```

This is working fine. But I want to add a file upload option in the form and save the uploaded file location to MySql. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add one field into your html form. and add parameter for into form.

```
<form method="post" class="container" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label>File</label>
        <input type="file" name="myfile" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

then after submit you have to save uploaded file at particular location and save that file into your db.

```
if (isset($_POST['BtnSubmit'])) {
    $target = 'uploads/' . basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $fp = fopen($target, "r");
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $data_array = array(
                    'myname' => $_POST['myname'],
                    'statename'  => $_POST['statename'],
                    'filename' => $target
                 );
}
```

I think it will work for you !! feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I still have a problem with the location of the file uploaded. I want to save the full-path of the file uploaded whereas this only save the filename. Thanks for help.